# Monitor local Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Is it possible to get Information out of the Azure function SDK?

For example the *Function URI*. Or the *count of Functions* running local.
Somthing like Swagger for local Azure Functions would be the goal.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I remember trying to use something similar to swashbuckle for Azure Functions, but there was no easy way to integrate it. This may help: [AzureFunction Swagger Definition Generator](https://github.com/wobba/AzureFunction-SwaggerDefinition)

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Function's OpenAPI 2.0 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-api-definition) may provide some of the functionality you are desiring. Note that as of April 2018, it is still in preview.